# PHP Array in Javascript Variable - JS Element

Tags: php, javascript

I have a Javascript variable which I am setting a PHP variable to.

```
function cancel(number) {
    var message = "<?= $message[" + number + "]; ?>";
}
```

$message is an array. "number" is the element of the array I want to set message to. Basically, I want to set a Javascript variable to a PHP variable using a Javascript variable as the element picker. So if "number" was 2, it would select:

```
$message[2];
```

However, the above approach doesn't work, and I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. Use XHR to retrieve the value from the server.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem at all possible;  PHP is evaluated server-side, and javascript is evaluated client-side.  So PHP would see it as `$message["+number+"]`, and try to find the value at the index of `"+number+"`.  You'd probably have to do something like an AJAX request to get the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing isn't possible; since php is a server-side language, it's executed first, and the js is executed after; there isn't any way to control which is executed first.  You must retrieve the variable using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot do this using this methodology. PHP is server-side code, meaning that it runs on the server, while JavaScript is client-side code, meaning it runs on the client, or your browser.

Once the PHP runs, it generates an HTML document and sends that document in the response to the browser. Once that's complete, the only way you can get data back to the server is to send it via a form POST, send it via AJAX, or send it via script tag remoting.

Consider looking at some examples on the Internet of how to POST data back to the server via a form and via AJAX. It's clear you're struggling with some concepts regarding how to properly architect your program, and looking at some examples would be a great way for you to learn and master these techniques.

- [PHP Submit Form Example](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formvar.php)
- [PHP Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var messages = <?= json_encode($message) ?>;

function cancel(number) {
    var message = messages[number];
}
</script>
```

Of course this will output the entire array in the JavaScript source. If it is large, then you are better off using AJAX.

Tip: if you "view source" it should be painfully obvious why your method doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use AJAX call to resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry about it. I saw the code more clearly a while later while formatting a better answer.